# Email me when list item = (modified date = 180 days old)

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

So i have a content approval list built to organize permission requests with a workflow to email me when a new list item is created as well as another to inform the creator when that list item is approved. I also have retention set up to email the creator there list item has reached 6 months.

I would like to set up 1 more workflow to email an admin that this list item has surpassed 6 months. BUT IM LOST lol

I have SharePoint 2013 and utilize SharePoint 2010 WorkFlows. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 6 months from when?  6 months from when the item was created, or item was last modified, or was approved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With just about any other type of Workflow engine, I would suggest running a scheduled workflow that runs once a day that uses a filtered REST call to find all items that are 6 months old.  Unfortunately, one of the biggest things missing from 2010 workflows is the ability to query for multiple items.

What 2010 workflows does have is the ability to "Pause".  If you are looking to be alerted 6 months from the date the Item is created, then you can add these steps to your existing On Created workflow, after it emails the notifications about creating, it can initiate the "Pause" action here.  If you need to base it on some other Date in the metadata that may change, then you will need to create a new workflow triggered on item creation and update.  It will probably only have two steps, one to `Pause for 180 days`, and then the next step would sent the email notification.

[image: Screenshot of Pause Action]

To make this send the mail notification when it has been more than 180 days since the Item was modified, set this workflow to be triggered on Item Created and Item Updated, then the next step After the `Pause` action should check if the current date is greater than (the Item's modified date + 180 days), and if so, send the email, otherwise nothing.  You will end up with multiple instances of this workflow being in progress for each item, once for every time the item is updated, but when each instance "wakes up" 180 days later, it checks again to see if it is still 180 days old before sending the email.

Note that due to the limitations of 2010 workflows not being able to simply query and loop through items, if you have any PowerShell skills, you may be better off writing a scheduled PowerShell script than implementing this complicated workflow.

Comment: So the objective here was to send an email when the "Modified" column on any given item is 6+ months old. (Current process: User submits request, Admin receives email of new request, Admin applies permissions to appropriate groups then approves user's request. User receives email of approved request as well as a warning that they must update this request every 6 months to avoid any interruptions. (6 months Pass) User receives email that there initial request has reached 6 months as well as directions on how to update.) I want the Admin to receive an email if the user does not update this??

Comment: I updated the answer with additional details -- if you are interested in the PowerShell approach, I can post an additional answer with some sample code.

Comment: would you be able to submit another answer with the powershell option, I don't think that will work for me, but maybe another individual would appreciate it.

Comment: I think what you have submitted thus far, will be more than helpful for my issue. Thank You very Much!

Comment: I went ahead and posted the powerShell option, I know you can only accept one answer, but you can always upvote more than one :).

Answer (score 0):

While the workflow option obviously allows you to avoid any custom code or server-side access, a PowerShell script could actually give you a simpler, arguably more elegant solution.

You could schedule this script to run nightly using the built-in Windows Task Scheduler on your SharePoint App Server.  Be sure to change the web url and list name in the code below, as well as changing the `$emailSubject` and `$emailBody` to match what you want to send:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ea SilentlyContinue
$web = get-spweb "http://mywebapp"
$list = $web.lists["MyUserRequestsList"]
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery

$query.Query = '<Where><Leq><FieldRef Name="Modified" /><Value Type="DateTime"><Today OffsetDays="-180" /></Value></Leq></Where>'

$query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'"
$query.RowLimit = 1000

do
{
    $listItems = $list.GetItems($query)
    $query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
    foreach($item in $listItems)
    {
        $emailSubject = $item["Title"] + " has not been updated in 6 month!"
        $emailBody = "You have not changed " + $file.LeafName + " since " + $item["Modified"] + ".  Please go to " + ($web.url + "/" + $list.rootfolder.url + "/dispform.aspx?id=" + $item.id) + " to update Now!"
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::SendEmail($web ,0,0,"important@person.com",$emailSubject,$emailBody)

    }
}
while ($query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)
```